# Win Form app wont show notify icon even when enabled

Tags: c#, winforms

A tray icon doesn't show up when the windows is minimized even though it should. This is the code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;

            Hide();
        }
    }

    private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        notifyIcon.Visible = false;
    }
```

When the window is minimized the it does the correct "Hide()" method, just not the notification icon. theres no way to open it after this. Theres an object with that name and I get no errors.

Initialize component in the Form1.Designer.cs looks like this

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // notifyIcon
            // 
            this.notifyIcon.Text = "notifyIcon";
            this.notifyIcon.DoubleClick += notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.Resize += Form1_Resize;
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
    }
```

anything im missing? thanks!

Comment: Make sure there is an icon.

Comment: I have to set an icon? Is there a default icon i can use?

Comment: It is called NotifyIcon.  You can test with `notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;`

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot!